# Muay Thai, how to Parry Teep Kick in a Safe way

Tags: self-defense, mixed-martial-arts, muay-thai, krav-maga, streetfight

Does anyone have tips for safely Parrying/Blocking the Muay Thai Teep Front Kick? This is specifically to the parry/hand tactic they teach below. This tactic works in practice, but it seems in a real fight, it can twist/shatter my elbow or hand if not done properly.

1. Any expert advice in doing this safe and effectively would be great.
2. Additionally, would this tactic work in a real street fight in self defense without boxing gloves? Maybe people in Krav Maga would know.

Resource Teep defense: https://youtu.be/b2GY7k8M_XU?t=58

https://youtu.be/kfmO67CN7fY?t=36

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The defense is relatively safe without gloves and works perfectly if done correctly. Two points to consider:

1. Side-step and close a bit of distance to the opponent plus a slight turn to avoid getting hit regardless and open up the possibility for counters. This also means you do not need to do the parry itself as a powerful move.
2. Do not try to do the parry as a powerful move (). No, seriously, it is rather a slap with a relaxed hand than an actual strike with force. That way, the parry is more efficient and you do not risk extra strains on the elbow or bones.

Background is Krav Maga in this case. That parry is widely acknowledged across every applied self-defense I encountered so far though, may it be in Judo, Japanese Jiu Jitsu, or Gracie Jiu Jitsu.

---

**Edit to answer comments**

1. Heavier opponents: The technique works just fine even against heavy opponents and legs. The point of a parry is not to move the leg much. But it still is more than enough since the main defensive action is the side-step anyway. It is to support the side-step with a minimal deflection. The change of direction itself is mainly due to the parry breaking their balance rather than actually moving the leg. And no matter how big they are, muscles able to counter the lateral force against an outstretched leg are non-existing.
2. Timing and injury risk: There is a similar technique for deflecting cross punches that are much faster. Still, you always hit the arm within 20 cm of the arm. Similarly, with minimal training, you will reliably hit at the right spot. As your force comes from the side, it is almost impossible to twist your arm. Additionally, your frontward side-step and reaction time will make it virtually impossible to get your hand in front of the kick.

Comment: thanks, I agree with point 1 side step, I do that all the time, and number 2 where its a slight misdirect from hand;  however I am concerned about "works perfectly if done correctly", I am worried that if I mess up, they may push my hand with a shoe on street defense, if one of us slightly messes up eye-hand coordination by a few seconds, and  it can damage hand, I will practice/test around with more

Comment: imagine if it was heavier weightclass, today I am 160, matched up with a guy 210 pounds today in muay thai class; punches, knees, and  high leg blocks generally work in any weight class, generally hand parry on a big leg, is different ball game, thanks for the info, and feel free to clarify any points ! thanks

Comment: Kyokushin Karate's front kick is pretty much identical to the teep and we also use this defense against it. I fully agree with #1. In all of those pictures, if you look carefully, you'll notice that, even at full extension, the kick barely reaches the target's body. That's because the actual "defense" part is stepping backward or to the side, with the hand sweep being used to twist your opponent around so that you face his side/back.

Comment: @Dungarth I suppose you cannot agree with the second part since kyokushin is a hard style with a lot of conditioning? I agree that you *can* do this as a really hard strike which can hurt like hell. But as mentioned, it needs a lot of conditioning over a long period of time. This, I cannot assume as a given for self-defence. That, and the old "hard vs. soft and vice versa" are the reasons I wrote it the way I did 

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking - lots of conditioning, yes, but conditioning was never intended as a substitute for technique. In other words, we try to do this block as smoothly as possible just like you describe, but we'll condition our arms so that if/when smooth isn't an option, we can still do the technique yet reduce the risk of injuries.

Comment: @Dungarth Sure, there still needs to be technique. I'd question that in the case of this one, "smooth isn't an option" actually happens, but I agree that conditioning is to prepare for cases when something goes wrong in general. I myself prefer conditioning over relying on perfect technique since nothing is perfect in self-defense.